# How do I visualize/explore a large volumetric data set with scipy?

Tags: scipy, data-visualization, mayavi

I have a 1000x1000x300 array, and I'd like to render it as voxels to explore the data set interactively in realtime.

Ideally I'd like something:

- Supports large data sets with a reasonable framerate (probably gpu accelerated)
- Scriptable from Python (so I can change data and re-render instantly, ala matplotlib)
- Supports color voxels

A nice bonus would be if I could add buttons, support mouse clicks, etc from the display, to support my own interactive ways of working with the data.

I tried Mayavi, but it seemed to choke on the data set size. Maybe I did something wrong?

I'm currently using osirix lite (radiology software), but I can't script it, it only supports monochrome data, it has a cap on array size due to being the lite version, and most importantly its very tedious to import and re-display data when I make changes to the data set.

Comment: Suggest you look into direct VTK (which mayavi layers on top of, with rather a lot of clutter) or the promising new project vispy (or one of its predecessors like visvis). For a full application solution, you could try 3d slicer.

Comment: wow, all of these are interesting, thank you!